# Delete specific values from data frame with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to cut the noise out of time waves, I want to delete specific but different values in the rows of a very big data frame. I could find only options of deleting whole rows or columns, but this is not what I need.
one row corresponds to a measurement id (30k in total) and one column to a time step (2500 in total). 
The data frame looks like this:
x1, x2, x3, ....., x2500
-0.001213, -0.001699, 0.003154, ..., -0.001213
0.000243, -0.009706, -0.003397, ..., 0.002184
etc

I selected the data to keep with a for-loop comparing thresholds and stored them in an np.array with ones and zeros.

I need the selected data in a new data frame (for making a csv) for further processing. 
** The selected data should only consist of the values of the old dataframe for which there is a 1 in the selection-array on that position.**
Thanks for any helpful advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please [Provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For starters, post your np array, give a feel of your row and column which needs to be cut etc.

Answer (score 0):

To modify specific values in a row of a data frame, you can use the applymap method.

Suppose you have a list of values you want to replace inside your data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

value_to_remove=[4,6,10]

arr=np.reshape(np.arange(16),(4,4))
df=pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df=df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x in value_to_remove else x)
```

If you need to modify values inside a specific row, use map instead:

```
df.loc[1]=df.loc[1].map(lambda x: np.nan if x in value_to_remove else x)
```